# OpenCV real-time camera image not moving

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to run the most simple script for viewing the laptop's camera in real time. But unfortunately after starting the window shows, but I get only a single frame displayed that doesn't ever get updated.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('test', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(-1):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

I was following tutorials for installing this on Windows and installed it on separate environment, using pip and downloaded wheel.  The window shows OK, and the image from camera is displayed but static. The program isn't hanged however, because it awaits a key being pressed and closes correctly afterwards.

What can be the cause?

Comment: waitKey(-1) waits until you press a key... choose a value > 0

Answer (score 0):

Try using this loop:

```
while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('test', img)
    keypressed = cv2.waitKey(30)
    if keypressed == ord('q'):
        break
```

The argument of `cv2.waitKey(delay)` is the delay in millisecond and the returned value is the key pressed:

> The function waitKey waits for a key event infinitely (when ≤0 ) or for delay milliseconds, when it is positive.  [..]
>
> It returns the code of the pressed key or -1 if no key was pressed before the specified time had elapsed.

See: https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7

Comment: I was reading that doc it's true, but only now that you wrote that I realized that I was waiting indefinitely in a loop in first iteration. once again thanks for hint

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will work it is fast and easy solution.

you can capture image by pressing c and q for quit the window

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
count=0 
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("imshow",frame)
    key=cv2.waitKey(30)
    if key==ord('q'):
        break
    if key==ord('c'):
        count+=1
        cv2.imwrite('/home/user/Desktop/image'+str(count)+'.png', frame)

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```